# Set $_SESSION['callback'] = 'no' if $_SESSION['callback'] == 'yes'

Tags: php, session

I have a function the gathers information regarding if you have any callback to a company in the next ten minutes. Everything works fine, except one thing. I want to display a JavaScript alert if a callback is found. I set $_SESSION['callback'] to 'yes' and redirect.

At page #2 I check if $_SESSION['callback'] is 'yes', if it is I output the JS code and set $_SESSION['callback'] to 'no'.

This does not work as one would think it would. It sets $_SESSION['callback'] to 'no' but it doesn't output the JS code, not even if I set $_SESSION['callback'] to 'no' in a separate if-clause.

This is the code that's problematic:

```
if(@$_SESSION['callback'] == 'yes') {
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Du har en återkoppling till detta företag inom tio minuter!');</script>";
    $_SESSION['callback'] = 'no';
};
```

Comment: it would probably be better to use `true` and `false`.

Comment: Is it because of special chars in alert text ?? `"Du har en återkoppling till detta företag inom tio minuter!"`

Comment: Check for error in your browser console

Comment: @PrasanthBendra: No, it's not. I've tried `echo "test";` as well and that didn't work either. I'm currently trying out the boolean thingy.

Comment: This is strange. Maybe the `script` element is actually written in the result but does not get executed by the browser for some reason ? Have you checked that ?

Comment: You should get rid of the habit of using `@` by default, if you want to get in the habit of producing quality code. Even in this case, there might be an error that you're not seeing because you're hiding it. You might not have run `session_start()` for example, which would show up as a notice when trying to access the variable from `$_SESSION`.

Comment: @Spudley: Your solution didn't work either. Same problem.

Comment: @Fabien: Yes, nothing is outputted at all. Nothing.

rid: I suppose, but that is irrelevant here, don't you think?

Comment: have you tried echoing $_SESSION['callback'] to see if it's yes or true or whatever?

Comment: @JeffHawthorne: Yes. It has the correct value.

Comment: Or maybe your if statement is happening in a point where output buffering is catching all output, so the echo never makes to the browser.

Comment: Actaully @rid's comment might be the most relevant ;) If it doesn't echo anything you probably don't pass the if condition and 'callback' is set to "no" somewhere else in the code. `var_dump` the `$_SESSION` before the "if" to check if it's ok.

Comment: @rid: I've rewritten the code to check with isset() whether $_SESSION['callback'] is set or not.

Comment: @Perplexor, alright, can you post what `$_SESSION` contains before the `if` statement?

Comment: @rid: How embarrassing, it contains "boolean false". Now I just have to figure out why it isn't set to true...

Comment: However, just before the redirect it's set to "boolean true".

Comment: @Perplexor, try to look through the entire code base for `_SESSION.*callback` (regexp), because if it's `false`, then it was certainly set to `false` explicitly somewhere.

Comment: Ok, I just commented out "$_SESSION['callback'] = FALSE;" (inside the if-clause) and it works. If I put that back, it doesn't.

Comment: @Perplexor, if it's not set to `false` anywhere else in the app, then check if the page that contains that `if` gets refreshed or redirected. (use the browser's inspector to check)

Comment: @rid: It does not. This is just too weird. :-S

Answer (score 0):

The following example doing exactly what you want. If it's the with your version, then you should start digging the contents of $_SESSION and other values.

You will see the alert box at first time, then it won't work when you refresh the page.

```
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['callback'])) $_SESSION['callback'] = 'yes';

if($_SESSION['callback'] == 'yes') {
    echo "<script>alert('hello!');</script>";
    $_SESSION['callback'] = 'no';
}

?>
```

Comment: If the variable isn't set, then there should be no JS alert. Besides that, this is the code I've got and it doesn't work until I remove `$_SESSION['callback'] = 'no';`.